# Displaying pictures in Gallery without showing other Gallery functions

Tags: android, gallery

I want to display pictures in the Gallery but without giving the user the capability to manipulate/send them or change the settings of the Gallery application.

Currently I am using the following code:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivity(intent);
```

When I am using ACTION_PICK, the Gallery is opened in "clean" mode without all those functions (manipulate image, send image, change settings, etc) and this is what I am looking for but with ACTION_VIEW intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are hundreds, if not thousands, of "gallery" apps, both pre-installed on Android devices and downloaded from places like the Play Store.

There are no options on `ACTION_VIEW` to allow you to request "manipulate/send them or change the settings". And there is no requirement that every gallery application honor such a request, even if there were a way to express it.

`ACTION_VIEW`, and similar implicit `Intents`, are for linking to third-party apps, where those third-party apps can do what they want. In that respect, it is like linking to a Web site -- you cannot control, from your site, what another site shows the user.

If you need absolute control over the UX here, write your own image viewer.

Comment: I am talking about the android built-in Gallery app, and I want to disable all functions except displaying images. Where can I find all the ACTIONS that  the Built-in Gallery app supports?

Comment: @Andy: There are hundreds of "android built-in Gallery app" implementations, across the thousands of Android device models. You would need to contact every device manufacturer and ask them what APIs they expose.